# Explode a special string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a annoying problem. I can't explode the string "`animation<br> adventure<br> action`". I need to delete "`<br>` " (with a whitespace) and get the result into an array.

Can someone help me with this?

I have tried:

```
$genre = explode("<br> ", $genre);
$genre = explode( "<br>\n", $genre)
$genre = preg_split('/<br[^>]*>\s*/i', $genre);
```

The following code gives me `( [0] => animation<br> [1] => adventure<br> [2] => action )`:

```
$genre = explode(" ", strip_tags($genre));
```

But I need to get rid of the "`<br>` ".

**UPDATE**

It's working if I use:

```
$genre = "animation<br> adventure<br> action";
$genre = explode("<br> ", $genre);
```

But not if I use `$genre` that fetches the result from the database. Inside `$genre` I have saved the string. It looks like "`animation<br> adventure<br> action`" if I print `$genre`. The result from the database won't explode, why?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if you really have `<br>` in the string, and not `&lt;br&gt;`?

Comment: Nope, sorry, that worked -> `$genre = explode("&lt;br&gt;", $genre);`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
$genre = explode("&lt;br&gt;", $genre);
```

Thanks to @Marc B.

Comment: Oh... I cannot believe I made this error too... Facepalm... How could I forget?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it with str_replace

```
$genre = str_replace('<br> ', ' ', $genre);
$genre = explode(' ', $genre);
```

You can also use any symbol to split your $genre, if your string contains whitespaces.

```
$genre = str_replace('<br> ', ',', $genre);
$genre = explode(',', $genre);
```

Comment: Still gives me: `( [0] => animation<br> [1] => adventure<br> [2] => action )`

Comment: you should fix your answer to handle strings containing spaces (E.g. `adventures<br> even better adventures`)

Comment: @Treps i would then stick to the comment by Marc B, it seems your string doesnt contain "<br>" but an encoded version

Answer (score 0):

This is working just fine.

```
$genre = "animation<br> adventure<br> action";
$genre = explode("<br> ", $genre);

print_r($genre);
```

[Here's](http://ideone.com/HWGGiV)the result

Comment: Hmm, when I do it like you it works, but when I get `$genre` from the database it doesn't work. :S

Comment: @Treps Moral of the story is whoever stored the data in the database should have been more careful.

Answer (score 0):

You could explode on `<br>`, and then use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on each element to get rid of the whitespace at the start and end of the string:

```
$array = array()
foreach(explode('<br>', $string) as $value){
    $array[] = trim($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php) to remove all html tags. The second parameter (optional) can be filled with tags you do not want to remove. Take a look at the documentation/manual for more information.